# When is an object updated in Ignite cachestore with write-behind enabled?

Tags: java, ignite

I have a Ignite Cache like this:
    IgniteCache cache;

The cache is configured with:

```
<property name="readThrough" value="true" />
<property name="writeThrough" value="true" />
<property name="writeBehindEnabled" value="true" />
```

And a CacheStore for a MariaDB 3rd party persistence.

```
<property name="cacheStoreFactory">
    <bean class="javax.cache.configuration.FactoryBuilder"
        factory-method="factoryOf">
        <constructor-arg>
           <bean class="my_backend_bean">
                                <constructor-arg value="jdbc:mariadb://xxxxx" />
                                <constructor-arg value="user" />
                                <constructor-arg value="password" />
                            </bean>
                        </constructor-arg>
                    </bean>
                </property>
```

This seems to be working well in general. I see storing objects with cache.put(key,object) returning quickly, while the MariaDB is updated asynchronously.

However, I'm experiencing the some issues where the MariaDB is not always updated with the latest values of the objects. I'm trying to find the reason for this.

So here are my questions:
- if I do cache.put("1", object) once, then change a property in the object, then do cache.put("1", object) again, will Ignite call the write method of the cache store backend bean again for updating the MariaDB? I see this is happening on my tests but wonder when might Ignite not update the cache store? What shows Ignite that the object was modified for the same key? Are there circumstances when Ignite hasn't written the first object to the store yet and the second cache.put is called, will this cause the issue not updating the cache store?
- should I better check cache.containsKey and then call cache.replace instead of cache.put? Or will replace actually call the delete function of my cache store backend bean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When write behind is used, data can be flushed either when buffer is full, or based on timeout. If you don't see an update, most likely none of the conditions was reached yet. Please read here for more details: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/3rd-party-store#write-behind-caching

Comment: Thanks, I did read this doc before. However, I'm seeing missing store updates where later puts to the same cache actually made it into the store. This shouldn't happen with the two mentioned events (timeout, buffer full), if I'm understanding this correctly, right? I think I need to add more logging to my CacheStoreAdapter to see what's actually happening. Am I right that cache.replace instead of cache.put makes no difference for the behavior of the persistent cache?

Comment: Are you saying that you update the same key twice, and only the second one is propagated into the DB? If so, this is correct behavior and you can change it with `CacheConfiguration#writeBehindCoalescing` parameter. If it is `false`, a new update will not override other updates for the same key that are currently in the buffer.

Comment: No, what I saw was that the second updates where not propagated into the DB. I added more log messages and realized there were some issues in certain situations when writing to the DB. It seems to work now, I don't see this issue anymore since a couple of tests. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@DonTequila
Upon Checking your configuration, Did you add any connection pool to your datasource

- Is your Datasource is getting connections from Connection pool? I couldnt see from your configuration
- Attach to Ignite configuration [ DataSource Pool]
  [Link to External Datasource](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/persistence/external-storage)
- Example doesnt have any Datasource , you can configure like below [ Provided you are using spring bean configuration]
- Monitor DB Session in MariaDB, how much Connections are created if it is 2 active, then this might choking delay of Ignite writing to the Cache Store

```
  <bean id="dataSourceEx" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mariadb://xxxxx" />
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="pwd" />
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="20" />
    <property name="minimumIdle" value="10" />
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="30000" />
    </bean>
```